# DataGrid is empty on loaded event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid, windows-xp

I have DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid name:"DG" ItemSource="{Binding}"/>
```

And fills it this way:

```
DG.ItemsSource = DataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

I need to change columns headers. I used this way:

```
<DataGrid name:"DG" ItemSource="{Binding}" Loaded="FormatColumns"/>

DG.Columns[i].Header = "Name";
```

On my PC it works well, but as i launch this soft on PC with Windows XP, i realise that `DG` have 0 columns as it `Loaded`.

Here is lots of code like:

```
DG.Columns[i].Header = "Name";
```

And it's better to just use it after another event. So is here any event i can handle and manually set all headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised. If `DataSet` is empty `DataGrid` is not fills with empty columns as i launch this program on Windows XP. Here is just completely empty `DataGrid`.

So, here is dirty solution:

```
if (DataGrid.Columns.Count == 0) return;
```

Comment: so you answered your own question?